# Image in HTML email is shifted right and displays a black border on the left

Tags: html, windows, email, outlook

I'm having a problem with the way the BODY.jpg image is displaying on Outlook on Windows.

It works fine in various browsers on a Windows and is good on Mac Outlook.

The trouble is the image is shifting slightly to the right cutting off a bit of the image and leaving a large black border on the left. Here's the code I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Pre-Sale</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

<!-- header -->
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
   <td>

  <table bgcolor="#00000" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">


  <tr height="46">
   <td bgcolor="#00000" align="center" style="background-color:#000000; ">
    <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="248px" height="46px" style="display:block" /></a>
   </td>
   </tr>


  <tr>
   <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000" style="height: 55px; font-size:15px; font-family: arial narrow, sans-serif; line-height:25px; text-align: center;">
    <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/magnaflow_socialmedia/mpg_online/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882_ONLINE_VERSION.html" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/VIEW_ONLINE.jpg" /></a>
       <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/automotive-performance/exhaust-systems/" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/CAT_BACKS.jpg" /></a>
       <a href="https://www.magnaflow.com/catalytic-converters/catalytic-converters/" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/CONVERTERS.jpg" /></a> 
       <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/automotive-performance/headers/" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/HEADERS.jpg" /></a>
       <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/automotive-performance/mufflers/" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/MUFFLERS.jpg" /></a>
       <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/automotive-performance/diesel-performance-exhaust/" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/DIESEL.jpg" /></a>
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/SPACER.jpg" alt="spacer" width="600px" height="2px" style="display:block" /></td>
  </tr>


 <tr height="34">
  <td bgcolor="#00000" align="center"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/DOWNLOADS.jpg" alt="DOWNLOADS" width="600px" height="34px" style="display:block" /></td>
 </tr>

  <tr>
   <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000" style="height: 93px;">
    <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/b2b/mpg/load_sheets/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882_Load_Sheet.xls" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882/LOAD_SHEET.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882_ISHEET.pdf" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882/I_SHEET.jpg"/></a>

    <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882.zip" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882//ASSETS.jpg"/></a> 
   </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/SPACER.jpg" alt="spacer" width="600px" height="2px" style="display:block" /></td>
 </tr>


  <tr>
   <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000"><a href="https://www.magnaflow.com/products?partNumber=17882&amp;searchTerm=17882"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882/BODY.jpg" alt="MAIN IMAGE" width="600" height="1918" style="display:block" /></a></td>
 </tr>



     <!-- COVERAGE TABLE -->
   <tr id="coverage">
    <td><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
     <tr bgcolor="#ffdd00" style="font-family:geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:13.5px; ">
      <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">PART</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">YEAR</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">ENGINE</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">PRODUCT</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">SERIES</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">TIP FINISH</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">EXIT</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">PIPE DIA.</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">MAP</td>
  </tr>

   <tr bgcolor="#e6e7e8" style="font-family:geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; ">
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle" ><strong>17882</strong><br /></td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" >1999-2002</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" >L6 5.9L</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" >TURBO-BACK</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" >CUSTOM BUILDER</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" >&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" >A</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" >4"</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" >$352.31</td>
  </tr></table>
    </td>    
    </tr>

  <tr bgcolor="#e6e7e8">
   <td><table id="coverage_table" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr style="font-family: geneva, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none;"><td align="center" valign="middle"> Excl. California; Excl. Vehicles With Catalytic Converter; Excl. Standard Cab </td></tr></table></td>
    </tr>

  <tr bgcolor="#e6e7e8"><td><table id="coverage_table" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"><tr style="font-family:geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none;"></tr></table></td></tr>

  <tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#000000"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/MPG_1999_2002_DODGE_RAM_17882/17882_SERIES.jpg" alt="COVERAGE TABLE HEADER" width="600" height="105" style="display:block; width:600px; height:106px; " /></td></tr>


  <tr height="42.5" style="font-family:geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none; color:#676767; "><td bgcolor="#212021" align="center" valign="center" syle="color:#ffffff;">CONNECT WITH US</td></tr>

 <tr>
   <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#212021" style="height: 42.5px; " >
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/magnaflow" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/FACEBOOK.png" /></a>
   <a href="http://instagram.com/magnaflow#" targaet="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/INSTAGRAM.png" /></a> 
   <a href="https://twitter.com/magnaflow" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/TWITTER.png" /></a>
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com/magnaflowtv" target="_blank" style="color:#9c9c9c; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.magnaflow.com/mpg/images/2016_PERFORMANCE_TEMPLATE/YOUTUBE.png" /></a></td>
 </tr>

 <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="footer">
      <td style="height: 120px; font-size: 10px; color: #666666; line-height: 11px; text-align: left; padding: 5px; padding-top: 30px; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">MagnaFlow and the MagnaFlow logo are either registered trademarks or trademarks of MagnaFlow in the United States and/or other countries. All other trademarks are the property of their respective owners.<br/>
        <br/>
        &copy; 2016 MagnaFlow. All rights reserved. <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/08aboutus/iso.asp" style="text-decoration: underline; color:#990000;" target="_blank">ISO 9001:2008 Certified - Registered Since 2000</a><br/>
        <br/>
        PLEASE DO NOT REPLY TO THIS MESSAGE.<br>To obtain information on how to contact MagnaFlow, visit the website at: <a href="http://www.magnaflow.com/08aboutus/contactus.asp" target="_blank" style="color: #990000;" >www.magnaflow.com</a>.<br>
        <br></td>
    </tr>
</table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "My image is being clipped, rescaled, or is not loading.": https://mailchimp.com/help/my-campaign-looks-bad-in-outlook it says: "This occurs in Outlook when a very long image is inserted in a campaign. The limit for image length is approximately 1728px tall and Outlook will clip the excess off the top of images taller than 1728px.", your image is 1918 pixels long. Eventhough your problem seems slightly different, splitting it up might help, perhaps? It can't hurt to try.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thanks for the tip.